# Binding TreeView with a ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I'm making a player in C#, by using Visual Studio 2010.
I'm looking for a way to display a playlist of files.
So I'm using a TreeView, and I want to bind it with an ObservableCollection.
My ObservableCollection :

```
public class Media
{
 string type; // Video, music, or picture
 string name; // example : 50-cent.mp3
 string path; // The path of the file
}

public class Playlist 
{
 string name; // The name of the playlist
 ObservableCollection<Media> list; // The list of Media
}
public ObservableCollection<Playlist> playLists = new ObservableCollection<Playlist>();
```

As you see, I have the var playlists, inside there are elements, and inside them, there are list of media.

I want to show this object in the wpf, and I think the best is TreeView.
I can't find in internet the way for binding TreeView and my var playlists.
I don't know how to make my TreeView in my WPF :S ... 
I read in internet that some people use HierachicalDataTemplate, but I really don't know how to do that exactly.

Help please

**EDIT
I'm trying the post given by David, I put my WPF**

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="1" Height="193" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,209,0,0" Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Playlist}" ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Media}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

I have problem, I still have nothing :S .
I did exactly like the tutorial :S

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I had tried to bind my object TreeView the ItemSource with the playlists.
But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have such effects as shown below:

[image]  [image]

You can have a look at this post: [WPF Treeview: data binding of heterogeneous types of data using CompositeCollection class](http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/?s=WPF%20tree)

Note: you need to derive your class from INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

```
public class Media : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
   string _name;
   string Name {
       get {return _name;} 
       set { _name=value; OnPropertyChanged("Name");}} //OnPropertyChanged is important!
   ...
}
```

See more help on INotifyPropertyChanged [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help, but I don't know why it doesn't works.
I put my WPF in edit part

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to provide us an XAML where you tries to bind a collection (I suppose you are using an [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx). As the second, I see that "list of Media" is private. As I know the private properties could not be bind.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind with `fields`. You can only bind to `Public Properties` in your class.

```
public ObservableCollection<Playlist> PlayLists { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hello, before in other project, I bound private ObservableCollection with a ListBox :S. 
Maybe I was lucky.

Comment: if your datacontext is the same class(code behind) as your xaml, then they are in the same scope and you shall be lucky enough