# Create all subfolders treeview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, treeview

I'm trying to create a treeView with all subfolders, and I follow a tutorial (https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/?s=WPF%20tree) and a SO answer to do it ([Binding TreeView with a ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593166/binding-treeview-with-a-observablecollection)), but I have a few problems with it.

Here is my code :

```
<TreeView Name="TreeName" ItemsSource="{Binding ListEtudes}">
   <TreeView.Resources>
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:FolderItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
       </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type IO::FileInfo}">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </TreeView.Resources>
```

And the code below :

```
public class FolderItem
{
    public DirectoryInfo Info { get; set; }

    public FolderItem (DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        Info = dir;
    }

    public FolderItem(string path)
    {
        Info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    }

    public string Caption
    {
        get { return Info.Name; }
    }
    public IList Children
    {
        get
        {
            var subDirItems = new List<FolderItem>();

            foreach (var dir in Info.GetDirectories())
                subDirItems.Add(new FolderItem(dir));

            return new CompositeCollection()
            {
                new CollectionContainer { Collection = subDirItems },
                new CollectionContainer { Collection = Info.GetFiles() }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Creation of `ListEtudes`, called once the view is called.

```
private ObservableCollection<FolderItem> listEtudes;
    public ObservableCollection<FolderItem> ListEtudes
    {
        get
        {
            if (listEtudes.Count == 0)
            {
                var root = new ObservableCollection<FolderItem>
                {
                    new FolderItem("C:\\temp\\")
                };
                listEtudes = root;
            }
            return listEtudes;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I follow the tutorial, but still have a few problems :

In xaml:
 `DataType="{x:Type FolderItem}"` --> FolderItem is not supported in a WPF project --> **Solution from TomerAgmon1 answer : need to define namespace and include it in the XAML. Edited.**

`DataType="{x:Type IO::FileInfo}"` --> The namespace prefix IO is not defined

In C#:
`public IList Children` --> Using the generic type 'Ilist' requires 1 type arguments

Honnestly, I don't understand what mistakes I make here, so any help would be usefull :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the xaml errors:
1. Specifiying `DataType` is optional. It's only so the Intellisense  would work with the bindings and you would avoid typing errors.
2. In `DataType="{x:Type FolderItem}"` you forgot to specify the namespace for `FolderItem`. You should define `xmlns:myModelNamespace="..."` at the top of the xaml file and then use `DataType="{x:Type myModelNamespace:FolderItem}"`.
3. `DataType="{x:Type IO::FileInfo}"` you wrote `::` instead of `:`. Is that a typing error? Also, I can't see if you correctly refrenced the `IO` namespace like I explained before.

Regarding the C# error...You forgot to specify the type of the `IList`. You should change the type of the property `Children` to `IList<SomeType>`.

Hope it helps

Comment: For the 1 and 2, that's work, just need to define the namespace and add it. For the 3, i define `xmlns:IO="clr-namespace:System.IO;assembly=WindowsBase"` at the beginning of the XAML file, still "the type reference cannot find a public type names 'FileInfo'
For the C#, the problem is that if I put a type for the list, the CompositeCollection's return became wrong, cannot implicitely convert etc.

Comment: Don't waste time on that...xaml designer doesn't always play along. It works in runtime, right?

Comment: And where exactly do you get thhe "Cannot implicitely convert..."?

Comment: If I add a type for the IList Children, the `return new CompositeCollection()` became an implicite conversion, since it doesn't get the Type I add to the IList

Comment: I don't know what's a CompositeCollection and why do you need it, but try also converting it to the same type. Like the error usually says afterwards..."are you missing a cast?"

Comment: Okay right, I was mimssing a cast. Thank's a lot for your patience and help, and pardon my english